# SignalR Javascript client can't connect, timeout occurs

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm trying to connect to a signalR server with Javascript client. I can't get the JS client to connect to the server. My debug output shows that the client first tries to subscribe to Websocket, then SSE and makes Long Polling request, all of them get timeouts. The server is client to another signalR server and there is no problem with that connection. But the JS client cannot connect.

I have the below packages:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin" version="1.2.1" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
```

My code is as below:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace CompanyPage
{

    public class Startup
    {
        [ExceptionAspect]
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR("/signalr", new HubConfiguration { EnableDetailedErrors = true });
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ExchangeRate>();
        context.Clients.All.insertOrder("TEST");
     }
```

.

```
$(function () {      
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;

    var chat = $.connection.exchangeRate;

    chat.client.insertOrder = function(message) {
        alert(message);
    };


    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
        console.log("Connection Started");
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you hooked the PreSendRequestHeaders event by chance? This might be related to the following issue: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3116 You can work around the issue by removing the PreSendRequestHeaders event or by downgrading to SignalR 2.0.3.

Comment: Yes the "official" solution we were given was to downgrade SignalR. It worked.